# C++ - Multi-Classes and Private Data Members

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm doing for my college a work in c++, my code is based on 2 classes, 
`NumSet` and `Game`.
data members are private.

```
class NumSet
{
    int arr[5];     //Cards
    int Score;
}

class Game 
{
    NumSet P1, P2;              //Player 1 , And Player 2 
    int OpenCard;               //For The Card in The center
}
```

for adding a score to P1 \ P2 from a method inside of `Game`
I created this method:

```
void NumSet::Addscore()
{
    ++this->Score;
}
```

and this other method:

```
void NumSet::PrintScore()
{
    cout << this->Score << endl;
}
```

Until now it all looks fine, but for some reason 
when I call the method `Addscore`:

```
P2.Addscore();
```

it raises its value from 0 to 2..

```
NumSet::NumSet()        //C'tor
{
    for (int i = 0; i < STARTCARDS; i++)
        arr[i] = NULL;
    this->Sort();       //BubbleSort
    Score = 0;
}

void Game::ChangeCards()
{
    if (x1 > x2)        //Player 1 is Stronger
        P1.Addscore();

    else if (x2 > x1)   //Player 2 is Stronger
        P2.Addscore();

    else                //Both Cards Are Equal
    {               //Checkin For The Lower Max Num
        int max1 = P1.Max();     //Max returns maximum num in arr
        int max2 = P2.Max();
        if (max1 < max2)
            P1.Addscore();
        else if (max2 < max1)
            P2.Addscore();
    }
}
```

I really would like an explanation of what's wrong in here.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please create a [minimal compilable sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code, that reproduces the behavior you describe?

Comment: @WillBriggs Hey , thanks for your reply , all the things you said is irrelavent becauce this things are already declared in the code but i hadnt copied it to here ..

Comment: @user1978011 sorry , thought i could get some help to get things together and understand , the code itself is alot larger and i made 90% of the work , i just want help for this P2.addscore thing ..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77115/discussion-on-question-by-unix14-c-multi-classes-and-private-data-members).

Comment: Here's the error, which is certainly predictable, that I get when I try to compile that:  `Cannot open include file: 'NumSet.h': No such file or directory`.

Comment: ..."Could you please create a minimal compilable sample of your code, that reproduces the behavior you describe? –  πάντα ῥεῖ "  This is why you're getting comments rather than solutions.  Do it and we can help you.

Comment: @unix14 Rolled back your edit. Just linking your actual code makes your question even worse. I've been asking you to create a minimal sample source code, that evidents to reproduce that behavior. This means **you reduce your source code**, until you have a (let's say not more than ~20 lines sample, alternatively highlight and link to a online ide like [ideone](http://ideone.com/) you can present here.

Answer (score 0):

nothing seems wrong here.. just make sure - 
1) Score is initialized to 0
2) Not doing any assignment or increment by mistake

Comment: @unix14 _"Uploaded Whole Code –"_ You didn't., you linked it, which is even worse than your original post. Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as mentioned!